# PowerShell / WMI to set MSNdis_currentpacketfilter

Tags: powershell, wmi

I like to know if there is a way to use PowerShell with WMI to set the MSNdis_currentPacketFilter

```
PS > Get-WmiObject -class "MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter" -NameSpace "root\WMI" -Filter "InstanceName='Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2'"

__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter
__SUPERCLASS            : MSNdis
__DYNASTY               : MSNdis
__RELPATH               : MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter.InstanceName="Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2"
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 3
__DERIVATION            : {MSNdis}
__SERVER                : HYPERV88
__NAMESPACE             : root\WMI
__PATH                  : \\HYPERV88\root\WMI:MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter.InstanceName="Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter
                          I350-T2"
Active                  : True
InstanceName            : Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2
NdisCurrentPacketFilter : 15
PSComputerName          : HYPERV88
```

And I would like to change the NdisCurrentPacketFilter value from 15 to 47.

I tried

```
Set-WMIInstance -Path ... -Arguments @{NdisCurrentPacketFilter=47}
```

But, got error.  Thanks in advance!

===== added 04/17/2015
Here were the commands I tried:

```
$p=$(Get-WmiObject -class "MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter" -NameSpace "root\WMI" -Filter "InstanceName='Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2'").__Path
Write-Host $p
\\HYPERV88\root\WMI:MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter.InstanceName="Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2"
Set-WmiInstance -Path $p -Arguments @{NdisCurrentPacketFilter=47}
```

and error (not sure why it said command not found, but command was valid)

```
Set-WmiInstance : Not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WmiInstance -Path $p -Arguments @{NdisCurrentPacketFilter=47}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance
```

And I tried this:

```
$o = Get-WmiObject -class "MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter" -NameSpace "root\WMI" -Filter "InstanceName='Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2'"
Write-Host $o
\\HYPERV88\root\WMI:MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter.InstanceName="Intel(R) Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T2"
Set-WMIInstance -class "MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter" -InputObject $o -Arguments @{NdisCurrentPacketFilter=47}
Set-WmiInstance : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WMIInstance -class "MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter" -InputObject $o -Arguments @ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance
```

Comment: Looks like its read only

Comment: I noticed that when I ran wireshark on the interface, wireshark will set it accordingly, and when wireshark exited, the value will be reset.

Comment: Wireshark might not use WMI to change it then

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this issue as according to [scriptinternals](http://www.scriptinternals.com/new/us/Support/Internal/WMI_MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter.htm) that value is read-only.

> NdisCurrentPacketFilter
>
> - Data type: integer/usint32
> - Access type: **Read-only**

I found similar information [here](http://wutils.com/wmi/root/wmi/msndis_currentpacketfilter/) as well. You should have wrote your error here as well. It might have added context to your issue and it is a best practice when asking questions.

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I know nothing about the class. Just wanted to see if anyone posted details of the class parameters.</sub>